# Why can't I move google instance from zone in one region to another zone in a different region?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

Using gcloud, I used to be able to move instances between the regions. Surprisingly, I couldn't do that anymore..!

The command I used:

```
cloud compute instances move instance-4 --zone us-east1-b --destination-zone asia-east1-b
```

I get the following error message:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.move) Some requests did not succeed:
 - Instances belonging to subnetworks cannot be moved interregionally.
```

Unfortunately, there isn't enough description about this error. Have Google changed the way moving instances is done? I know I can create a snapshot of the VM and start it in the new region but I wanted to use the 'move' command specifically. Is there something I didn't pay attention to?
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Migrate Google compute engine instance to a different region](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36441423/migrate-google-compute-engine-instance-to-a-different-region)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that command is to move between zones in the same region. I believe you have to use instant image and recreate in a different region.

Best of luck.

T